# after_sign_in_path not called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have simple RoR application with devise.

Here is the output ot rake routes

```
logout_index GET    /logout/index(.:format)        logout#index
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          devise/registrations#edit
                         PUT    /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#destroy
```

Here is the code in application_controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  def after_sign_in_path()
      abort 'signed'
   end
end
```

The problem is that when a user is signed up the method after_sign_in_path is not executed.
What I miss here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should be `after_sign_in_path_for`. See [here](http://devise.plataformatec.com.br/#getting-started/configuring-routes).